# Groovy- searching and excretion xml code from log file

Tags: parsing, groovy

I have so many texts in log file but sometimes i got responses as a xml code and I have to cut this xml code and move to other files.
For example:

```
sThread1....dsadasdsadsadasdasdasdas.......dasdasdasdadasdasdasdadadsada
important xml code to cut and move to other file: <response><important> 1 </import...></response>
important xml code to other file: <response><important> 2 </important...></response>
sThread2....dsadasdsadsadasdasdasdas.......dasdasdasdadasdasdasdadadsada
```

Hindrance: xml code starting from difference numbers of sign (not always start in the same number of sign)

Please help me with finding method how to find xml code in text
Right now i tested substring() method but xml code not always start from this same sign :(

EDIT:
I found what I wanted, function which I searched was indexOf().
I needed a number of letter where String "Response is : " ending: so I used:

```
int positionOfXmlInLine = lineTxt.indexOf("<response")
```

And after this I can cut string to the end of the line :

```
def cuttedText = lineTxt.substring(positionOfXmlInLine);
```

So I have right now only a XML text/code from log file.
Next is a parsing XML value like BDKosher wrote under it.
Hoply that will help someone You guys

Comment: <important="1"> isn't valid XML...what text from that "XML" are you trying to extract?

Comment: this xml is only example, i need to extract xml code after word "Response is :" <xml code.../> I tryied substring (numer of sign) but I find that not all xml codes starts from the same sign (like in example on top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to leverage [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper) for this, assuming your XML is valid enough. The code below will take each line of the log, wrap it in a root element, and parse it. Once parsed, it extracts and prints out the value of the `<important>` element's `value` attribute, but instead you could do whatever you need to do with the data:

```
def input = '''
sThread1..sdadassda..sdadasdsada....sdadasdas...
important code to cut and move to other file: **<response><important value="1"></important></response>**
important code to other file: ****<response><important value="3"></important></response>****
sThread2..dsadasd.s.da.das.d.as.das.d.as.da.sd.a.
'''

def parser = new XmlSlurper()
input.eachLine { line, lineNo ->
    def output = parser.parseText("<wrapper>$line</wrapper>")
    if (!output.response.isEmpty()) {
        println "Line $lineNo is of importance ${output.response.important.@value.text()}"
    }
}
```

This prints out:

```
Line 2 is of importance 1
Line 3 is of importance 3
```

Comment: Hi BDKosher, thanks for greate code but I need just cut all of xml code (parsing xml code will be in future) I just need cut xml code after Response is and put to other file. I opened other issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990241/groovy-how-to-get-string-in-text-to-cutting-this-string-away